# How do I position a div directly under a clicked on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with social icons listed across the page. When you click on one, I want a window to pop under with more information. Here is a picture of what I want it to look like after the user clicks on an icon.

[image]

That entire pop-over is self contained in it's own div.

I'm looking for a more dynamic method then just hard coding in different coordinates for each button.

Thanks in advance.

The Html

```
<div id='inset'>
    <div id='icon-gutter'>
        <div id='gutter-loader'>


        </div>
        <div id='icons'>
        <img src='images/facebook.png' id='facebook' />
        <img src='images/twitter.png' id='twitter' />
        <img src='images/google+.png' id='google+' />
        <img src='images/linkedin.png' id='linkedin' />
        <img src='images/reddit.png' id='reddit' />
        <img src='images/tumblr.png' id='tumblr' />
        <img src='images/pinterest.png' id='pinterest' />
        <img src='images/youtube.png' id='youtube' />
        <img src='images/lastfm.png' id='lastfm' />
        <img src='images/instagram.png' id='instagram' />
        <div id='pop-over-wrap'>
            <div id='arrow'>
            </div>
        <div id='pop-over-body'>
            Hello
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#inset {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url(grey-fabric.png) repeat; /*#001121;*/
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding: 14px 10px 10px 22px;

border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;

}
#icon-gutter {

    height: auto;
    min-height: 43px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#icons {
    opacity:0;
}
#icons img {

    height: 95px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 8px;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: all .2s;
-moz-transition: all .2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all .2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all .2s; /* Opera */

}
#pop-over-wrap {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: white;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 300px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');

}
#arrow {
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/arrowup.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -30px;

}
#pop-over-body {


}
```

Comment: I think you could use a `ul` for the icons and classes instead of the id's.

Comment: You're right. Not sure why I decided not to do that before. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margins on the `#pop-over-wrap` css rule, and handle the positioning through jQuery.

```
$(function(){

    var popup = $('#pop-over-wrap'),
        popupOffset = popup.outerWidth()/2,
        arrowExceed = 30; // how many pixel the arrow exceeds from the containing wrapper.

    $('#icons > img').click(function(){
        var icon = $(this),
            iconPos = icon.position(),
            iconW = this.width,
            iconH = this.height,
            popupTop = iconPos.top + iconH + arrowExceed,
            popupLeft = iconPos.left + iconW/2 - popupOffset;

        popup.css({left:popupLeft, top:popupTop});
        popup.show();
    });

});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/ALFfs/1/
*demo has hardcoded image widths because i have no access to the images..*

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! I prefer this method over others because It gives me the most control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create event on each img like this:

```
$('#icons').find('IMG').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){  
       var idBlock = $(this).attr('id');
        //Code of showing popup window idBlock type
          var htmlBasedonIdBlock = GetBlockHtml(idBlock)
         $('#pop-over-wrap').html(htmlBasedonIdBlock)
   })
})
```

GetBlockHtml function that gets html according on type of block

you use tipsy, so you need only make html for content of body and all work will be done by one

If you don't use tipsy for this, here a lot of other jquery plugins http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html) jquery plugin to accomplish what you want

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [CSS Tooltips and Speech Bubbles](http://konigi.com/tools/css-tooltips-and-speech-bubbles).

You don't exactly have to calculate the coordinates for those boxes. There are a lot of CSS3 tricks to do this one. Hey, you don't even have to use Javascript! However if you consider perhaps compatibility, consider using this [jQuery plugin](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html) for helping you do tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put each `img` in a `div` together with its pop over. Then you position the container div relative and position the pop over absolute?

Like this:

```
<div class="icon">
    <img src='images/facebook.png' id='facebook' />
    <div class="popover">
        <div id='arrow'>
        </div>
        <div id='pop-over-body'>
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in css:

```
.icon{
    position:relative;
}
.popover{
    position:absolute;
    left:-30px;
    top:10px;
}
```

You get the idea? It would be even nicer to put the icons in an unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div as a container for an image and a div with information.
For example:

```
<div id="container-1">
   <img src='images/facebook.png' id='facebook' />
   <div id="information-1" class="information-block hideElement"></div>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
   <img src='images/twitter.png' id='twitter' />
   <div id="information-2" class="information-block hideElement"></div>
</div>
```

Where

```
.hideElement { display: none; }
.information-block { position: relative; top: 10px; left: -20px; width: 100px;} //for example
```

And using jQuery you can show an information block for the first container when you click on the first container:

```
$("#container-1").click(function() {
   $("#information-1").removeClass("hideElement");
});
```